# Is it king or emperor in 1 Peter 2:17?

Tags: 1-peter

1 Peter 2:17 NIV

> Show proper respect to everyone, love the family of believers, fear God, honor the **emperor** [βασιλεύς].

Nero was emporor at the time.

Berean Literal Bible

> Honor everyone: love the brotherhood, fear God, Honor the **king** [βασιλεύς].

In https://biblehub.com/1_peter/2-17.htm, 8 versions use "emperor" and 24 versions use "king". Which is better?

Comment: Can we even be sure that he is not referring to Christ?!

Comment: Elaborate and I'll +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 1 Peter 2:17, the operative word is βασιλεύς (basileus) which is definitely "king" in English, and occurs about 115 times in the NT, eg, Matt 1:6, 2:1, 5:35, 10:18, etc.  Thayer offers the following meaning: "leader of the people, prince, commander, lord of the land, king".  When this refers unambiguously to the Caesar, it could be translated, Emperor".

In 1 Peter 2:17, only "king" is defensible unambiguously as it simply refers to the local head of government, whoever that might be, without excluding Caesar.

The word "Emperor" is Σεβαστός (Sebastos) and occurs only three times in the NT, namely, Acts 25:21, 25, 27:1.  Its meaning is clear: it was the official Latin title of the "Augustus", the emperor of Rome.  Note the meaning from Thayer:

> 1. reverend, venerable.
> 2. ὁ σεβαστός, Latin augustus, the title of the Roman emperors: Acts 25:21, 25 (Strabo, Lucian, Herodian, Dio Cassius, others); adjective
>    σεβαστός, σεβαστη, Σεβαστόν, Augustan, i. e. taking its name from the
>    emperor; a title of honor which used to be given to certain legions,
>    or cohorts, or battalions, for valor (ala augusta ob virtutem
>    appellata. Corpus inscriptions Latin vii. n. 340, 341, 344): σπείρης
>    Σεβαστῆς, the Augustan (Imperial) cohort, Acts 27:1 (λεγεών σεβαστη,
>    Ptolemy, 2, 3, 30; 2, 9, 18; 4, 3, 30). The subject is fully treated
>    by Schürer in the Zeitsehr. für wissensch. Theol. for 1875, p. 413ff

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if the placement of king after the directive to “fear God” is simply the completion of the directive Peter is giving…
Fear God (obey Him) and fearing God will involve honoring the authority of the leader God places over us.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The words, "king" and "kings" are used in Daniel to describe Rome's emperors. The emperors enjoyed a "kingly position" (having supreme military authority for life) following Julius Caesar's restructuring of his "emperor position". In that reconstructing process, he also laid claim to being a "**deity**" which would pass along to his heir (Octavian, etc.) upon his death. Because that claim of deity is a fraudulent encroachment upon the ONE TRUE GOD's claim of being the ONLY deity, the term, "king" should be the only acceptable term that could be **properly** expressed by Scripture--the very WORD of the ONE TRUE GOD.